# React-Bootstrap centering Tabs

Tags: css, react-bootstrap

Bootstrap-react's Tab's will align to the left by default.

```html
<Tabs defaultActiveKey={2} id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
  <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">
    Tab 1 content
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">
    Tab 2 content
  </Tab>
</Tabs>;
```

You can pass a `pullRight` prop to make it align to the right

```html
<Tabs pullRight defaultActiveKey={2} id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
```

Is there a simple way to make it centered? If not, how would you center the tabs?

Answer (score 2):

On your CSS file, put the following:

```
ul.nav.nav-tabs {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `fill` as a prop

```
<Tabs fill></Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
.nav-tabs > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
}

.nav-tabs {
  text-align: center;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/j751b1mb/4/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.centered-tabs > nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div className='centered-tabs'>
  <Tabs></Tabs>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was using the grid system in react-bootstrap and adding the class "nav-justified" to the column.

```
<Container fluid>
  <Row className={"justify-content-center"}>
    <Col className={"nav-justified"}>
      <Tabs defaultActiveKey="profile" id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
        <Tab eventKey="user" title="User"></Tab>

        <Tab eventKey="aboutMe" title="About Me"></Tab>

        <Tab eventKey="posts" title="Posts"></Tab>
      </Tabs>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>;
```